# Client-Server application not waiting for input

Tags: java, server, io

I am coding a psimple client-server application. When the string "list" is entered in to the client application, the server should send the names of the files in the "serverFiles" folder to the client which should then print the names. The client input is then read correcty but then nothing happens. After some debugging, it seems that the server is not waiting for the input from the client

The server code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Server
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
    {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8888);
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        while(true){
            SocketHandler socket = new SocketHandler(serverSocket.accept());
            service.submit(socket);

            socket.getWriter().close();
            socket.close();
        }

    }
}
```

,

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SocketHandler extends Thread {
    private Socket socket = null;
    private BufferedReader reader;
    private PrintWriter writer;

    public SocketHandler(Socket socket) {
        try {
            this.socket = socket;
            this.reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.socket.getInputStream()));
            this.writer = new PrintWriter(this.socket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not create buffered reader");
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        String string = null;
        try {
            while ((string = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(string);
                switch (string) {
                    case "list": {
                        listFiles();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void close() {
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not close socket");
        }
    }

    public void listFiles() {
        System.out.println("LISTING");
        File[] files = (new File("serverFiles")).listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            writer.println(file.getName());
        }
        writer.flush();
    }


    public Socket getSocket() {
        return socket;
    }

    public BufferedReader getReader() {
        return reader;
    }

    public PrintWriter getWriter() {
        return writer;
    }
}
```

The client code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client{
    public void listFiles(){

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        ClientHandler client = new ClientHandler();
        KeyboardScanner scanner = new KeyboardScanner();
        String string = null;
        while((string = scanner.getInput()) != null){
            switch(string){
                case "bye":{
                    client.close();
                    return;
                }case "list":{
                    client.listFiles();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class KeyboardScanner{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public String getInput(){
        return scanner.nextLine();
    }
}
```

,

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ClientHandler {
    private Socket socket = null;
    private BufferedReader reader = null;
    public PrintWriter writer = null;

    public ClientHandler(){
        try {
            socket = new Socket("localhost", 8888);
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        } catch(IOException e){
            System.err.println("Could not make connection");
        }
    }

    public void close(){
        try{
        socket.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
            System.err.println("Could not close connection");
        }
    }

    public void listFiles(){
        writer.println("list");
        writer.flush();
        String string = null;
        try {
            while ((string = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(string);
            }
        }catch(IOException e){}
    }
}
```

Comment: never silently swallow exceptions `catch (IOException e) {
        }`

Comment: You are closing the socket immediately after creating the `SocketHandler` and passing it to the executor `service`!  “Do this for me, oh never mind”